# jquery - use a variable outside the function

Tags: jquery, variables, definition

How I Can use a variable outside the function where it was declared?

```
$(function() {
    function init() {
        var bwr_w = $(window).width();
    }
    init();
    $('#button').click(function() {
        alert('The Browser Height is' + bwr_w);
    });
});
```

If I click on the button I get this error:

**bwr_w is not defined**

Answer (score 18):

Just declare that variable in constructor's scope:

```
$(function() {
    var bwr_w = null;

    function init() {
        bwr_w = $(window).width();
    }

    init();

    $('#button').click(function() {
        alert('The Browser Height is' + bwr_w);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
$(function() {
  var bwr_w = 0;
  function init() {
    bwr_w = $(window).width();
  }
  init();
  $('#button').click(function() {
    alert('The Browser Height is' + bwr_w);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you declare the variable outside the function, then assign a value to it *inside* the function, it should be accessible elsewhere. So long as you're sure that a value will be assigned. If you're not sure, you might want to assign a default value:

```
$(function() {

        var bwr_w; // or 'var bwr_w = default_value;'

    function init() {
        bwr_w = $(window).width();
    }
    init();
    $('#button').click(function() {
        alert('The Browser Height is' + bwr_w);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $(function() {
    var bwr_w_var = function() {
        let bwr_w = 'stack overflow';
        return bwr_w;
    };
    function() {
        let bwr_w = bwr_w_var();
        console.log(bwr_w);
    };
  });
```