# XMLHttpRequest and class attributes

Tags: javascript, ajax, class, attributes, xmlhttprequest

I have a some class (Hello), this class has foo property and this property must fill after xhr request. How to set `foo` from `XMLHttpRequest` and how to call `afterLoad()`?

```
function Hello(){

    this.foo = null;

    this.process = function(){
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', 'http://some.url', true);
        req.onload = function(){
            // How to set Hello.foo in this context?
            // And how to call Hello.afterLoad() from this context?
            // this == XMLHttpRequest instance
        };
        req.send(null);
    }
    this.afterLoad = function(){
        console.log(this.foo);
        // Some stuff goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: why not using a js framework for this ? like Jquery

Comment: [like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648028/jquery-use-a-variable-outside-the-function)

Comment: did you try using a helper like `var that = this;` before declaring the process function and access it like `that.foo = 'whateva'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Hello(){

  this.foo = null;

  this.process = function(){
    var _that = this,
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', 'http://some.url', true);
    req.onload = function(){
        // How to set Hello.foo in this context?
        // And how to call Hello.afterLoad() from this context?
        // this == XMLHttpRequest instance
        _that.foo = 'something';
        _that.afterLoad();
    };
    req.send(null);
  }
  this.afterLoad = function(){
    console.log(this.foo);
    // Some stuff goes here
  }
}
```