# Javascript init - Reading variables

Tags: javascript

I am stuck with a really simple problem. I have a function like below:

```
<script>
window.asanaInit = function() {
       asana.init({
          "aid":       "813E6A6A",
          "uid": "50.125"
       });
    };
console.log(aid);
</script>
```

How do I access the values of aid and uid in my javascript code?

Comment: What does `asana.init` ?

Comment: declare the variable outside the function.
reference : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648028/jquery-use-a-variable-outside-the-function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648028/jquery-use-a-variable-outside-the-function)

Answer (score 1):

From the code you provide, you don't have enough information to access `aid` or `uid`:

In the scope of window (the global scope), you have access to an object called `asana`. `asana` has a function `init` which receive an object as parameter. Whenever this parameter is saved or not is impossible to know without looking the source code of the function `asana.init()`.

I suggest you to lookup the object `window.asana`, to know if it contain any copy of those values, a getter o any alternative access to it.