# dataTable loaded through Ajax gives Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using dataTable.js to display sortable tables. The content of the page is loaded via AJAX, so I have to wait before initiating the dataTable until the AJAX request is successful.

This is all working as expected.

Now, I have a checkbox inside the table that is updating the records through some other AJAX code. After the checkbox is updated, the  data-sort attribute is also updated with jQuery. However, after I update the data-sort, I need to invalidate the dataTable rows using `.rows().invalidate();`.

But, as the table is initialized in a function, it returns an Uncaught ReferenceError that the dataTable is not defined, even though it is already defined and loaded via the function...

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: dateDataTable is not defined
```

This is the function that is called on AJAX success (working fine):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
   function loadMainDataTable() {
      var mainDataTable = $('.mainDataTable').DataTable( {
          scrollY: 315,
          order: [[ 0, "desc" ]],
      } );
    }
});
```

This is the call I make when the checkboxes get updated (not working fine):

```
mainDataTable.rows().invalidate();
```

This used to work well before I loaded the page content with AJAX. I cannot use the dateTable built-in AJAX functions, as I need to load the full page via AJAX, not just the table content.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out, thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5648066/4274031

I declared the variable `mainDataTable` outside the function, then updated it inside the function, like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var mainDataTable = null;
    var dateDataTable = null;

    function loadMainDataTable() {
      mainDataTable = $('.mainDataTable').DataTable( {
          scrollY: 315,
          order: [[ 0, "desc" ]],
      } );
    }

})
```